# How to access calculated values of geom_curve in ggplot2 (R)?

Tags: r, ggplot2, bezier, curve

I am looking for the calculated values of ggplot2 when applying `geom_curve`.

Herefore, a little reproducible example:

```
require(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(x=c(0,2), y=c(5,5))

plot <- ggplot() + 
geom_curve(data = df, aes(x = df[1,"x"], y = df[1,"y"], xend = df[2,"x"], yend = df[2,"y"]), 
         color = "red", linetype = 3, curvature = 0.4, size = 2)
plot
```

This plots a red curve between the two points of my data.frame. I am interested in the calculated values for plotting the arc, done by `geom_curve`. How can I access them?

I was looking at `ggplot_build(plot)` but did not succeed. E.g. in `ggplot_build(plot)$layout$finish_data` is function stored but I don't know how to access it.

Or in `ggplot_build(plot)$data` are just the definitions of the curved stored but I think the values have to be somewhere in `ggplot_build`.

I would like to get all the calulcated points of this `geom_curve` or store the applied function in my global environment.

Comment: I am not sure that this is possible. Anyway, `geom_curve` draws curves using the `grid::curveGrob` function. You should start from this function.

Comment: Yes, you're right - `geom_curve` is based on `grid::curveGrob`. How would it be possible to access the calculated values by `grid::curveGrob` then? @MarcoSandri

Comment: It's bad form to use the data frame inside `aes()` (it will mess up facets and some `stat` functions). Instead you can just do `aes(x = x[1], y = y[1], xend = x[2], yend = y[2])`

Comment: This GitHub thread is relevant: https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/2372 Thomasp85 suggests to use `ggforce` geoms instead